# How to setup game closure android development tools

Tags: gameclosure

I am struggling to setup android development  enviorment for game closure.

## problems

```
1. setup sdk
2. setup ndk
3. setup java
```

is there any option to setup java other than oracle JDK in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## for setting up android development

1. check this [link](http://docs.gameclosure.com/native/android-setup.html)
2. for java setup you can use open-jdk

   ## installation

   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre